Comparing Systems Based on Their Variance
I am using simulations to compare two economic models and want to understand their impact on returns (i.e., the percentage change in prices). I have employed common random numbers for these simulations and understand how to compare the models based on their mean returns following the methods described here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228039569_Comparing_Systems_via_Simulation 
However, I am also interested in comparing these models in terms of the variance of their returns, as this is a crucial measure of risk. The simulated data (returns) are highly skewed and not normally distributed, which complicates the comparison. While I am aware that I could compare the simulations pairwise and report the distribution of test statistics (Levene’s test seems ideal) for a large number of replications, I believe there might be a more effective method that leverages all the data.
Could someone please provide guidance on how to approach this comparison or suggest any readings that could help? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

So your question is how to compare a measure of dispersion of two arbitrary distributions?

I want to test whether the variance of returns identified with each model is different. I simulate data from each model, where the models differ in one respect. I want to isolate the causal effect of this treatment on the variance of returns. I generate 250 of these paired simulations and calculate the variance of each of the pairs, which are correlated because of the use of common random numbers. How can I create a confidence interval for the difference in variance between the models? What would be the best way to report these results? Thank you.
